# Subset list by varying index

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am trying to subset values from a list object based on a varying index.

I have tried the standard sub-setting strategies, like lapply. However, they only work for a fixed index. E.g., sub-setting the first value of every list element. Yet, I want to select a different index position in every list element.

Consider the following list:

```
mylist<-list(c("25","0","33"),c("50","1"),c("100","2","3", "45"),c("12", "54"))
```

I can easily subset for the first value in each list element using lapply:

```
lapply(mylist,"[", 1)
```

This gives me the first value in each list element. However, consider a situation in which I want the second value at the first element, the first value at the second element, the third value at the third element, etc.
Put differently, I would like to subset by a varying index, e.g.,:

```
var.index <- c(2,1,3,1)
```

So I receive the final values

```
c(0,50,3,12)
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can use `mapply` for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `mapply` with which you may loop through multiple ordered sets in the order of their elements.

```
mapply(function(x, y) x[y], mylist, var.index)
# [1] "0"  "50" "3"  "12"
```

Comment: Golden! Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `mylist` and `var.index` would have same length you could also use `sapply`/`lapply`

```
sapply(seq_along(mylist), function(x) mylist[[x]][var.index[x]])
#[1] "0"  "50" "3"  "12"
```